# Cant open a closed file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the code below to try and open a pdf file and I am getting the error cannot open a closed file? Not sure what I am missing here.

```
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FolderLocation As String = Nothing
    Dim FileFormat As String = "application/pdf"
    Dim tFileNameArray As Array = Nothing
    Dim tFileName As String = Nothing

    FileName = "\\Server\Files\45144584.pdf"

    Dim fs As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Using (fs)

    End Using
    Dim data() As Byte = New Byte(fs.Length) {}
    Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(fs)
    br.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
    br.Close()
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = FileFormat
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & tFileName.Split("\")(tFileName.Split("\").Length - 1))
    Response.BufferOutput = True
    Response.BinaryWrite(data)
    Response.End()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have all code that references `fs` inside of the using, otherwise you are attempting to access an object that has already been disposed. I would also do the same thing with the `BinaryReader`, since it also implements `IDisposable`:

```
Dim data() As Byte
Using fs As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    data = New Byte(fs.Length) {}
    Using br As New BinaryReader(fs)
        br.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
    End Using
End Using
...
```

Comment: Thanks! It asked me to insert missing "end using" but I didnt verify where it put it. All set now

Answer (score 1):

You have the following lines:

```
Using (fs)

End Using
```

After End Using, the file is closed and the fs object disposed of.

You need to put the code that reads from fs inside the using block.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim fs As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Using (fs)

End Using
Dim data() As Byte = New Byte(fs.Length) {}
...
```

You're trying to use `fs` after it has been disposed. This needs to be:

```
Dim fs As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Using (fs)
    Dim data() As Byte = New Byte(fs.Length) {}
    Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(fs)
    br.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
    br.Close() 
End Using
```